# Elevation Data not showing on Globe

Tags: elevation, arcglobe

Using ArcGLobe I'm attempting to display elevation data.

I'm using Digital Terrain Elevation Data (DTED) data and trying to load it in the following fashion.

```
IRasterLayer rasterLayer = new RasterLayerClass();
rasterLayer.CreateFromFilePath(myFilePath);
Globe.AddLayerType(rasterLayer , esriGlobeLayerType.esriGlobeLayerTypeElevation , true);
```

Nothing shows up on the globe.  Thoughts?  Ideas?

Comment: Is everything in the same coordinate system?

Comment: Same Question? http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7878/load-dted-data-files-into-arcglobe/7880#7880 ??

Comment: @Dan - Yes, it appears to all be within the same Coordinate System.

Comment: Any chance you could upload a small sample of your data somewhere?  Id like to replicate it myself.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This was a combination of bad DTED data and exageration not being set.

Comment: Shouldn't you give James the points then? I mean, you probably woud not have been able to open the data on ArcGlobe if it was bad.

Comment: I used other data and it still wasn't showing.  So while he was somewhat correct (bad data) the Exageration was the real answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your first test it to see if you can add the data through the standard ArcGlobe UI. If you can't add the data there, then there are other problems.